# Selenium:- Unable to write in the textbox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The click Event is working fine but sendKeys event is not.

My Code is:-

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("radio-1-4")).click();
 jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 500);");
 System.out.println("Authority Filter");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"filter-label-text\" and text()= 'Authority']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(3000);
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class=\"control-label\" and @for='tfid-665-0']//parent::div[1]/child::input")).sendKeys("Public Work Department");
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("tfid-602-0"));
 element.click();
 element.sendKeys("public");
```

I am getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#tfid\-602\-0"}
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

The HTML of the textbox is:-

```
<div class="form-group form-group-depth-1 form-group-search">
    <label for="tfid-664-0" class="control-label">
    </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for Authorities" id="tfid-664-0" name="search" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: The click doesn't work, the program never reached it. Since you have sleep I'm guessing the element is inside `<iframe>`,please check it.

Comment: Nope, Even after removing sleep function it's not working..
In this case i am even unable to find the exact XPath of the text box.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to show the HTML for ID="tfid-602-0" (currently you have Selenium looking for tfid-602-0, and showing HTML for tfid-664-0).

Comment: @RAHUL The point was that because you have sleep it's probably not a timing issue. Check if the element is inside `<iframe>` and make sure it's really `tfid-602-0`, in the html you posted the id is `tfid-664-0`.

Comment: Now i have just used By.name("search") 
Error is coming as :- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable


Struck here..!!

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.form-group-search>label.control-label[for^='tfid']"))).sendKeys("public");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @placeholder='Search for Authorities']//preceding::label[1]"))).sendKeys("public");
  ```